# How can I change project resource location in a project?

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I use Eclipse PDT and have setup some PHP projects. The resources for one project had to be moved into a different folder. Can I change the resource location without deleting the project an setting up a new one?

Via "Projects -> Properties" I can only see the location path, but I can't change it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right-click on the project -> Refactor -> Move

Or close the project, delete it (but do not delete content on disk), use terminal or file browser to move the project folder on disk, in Eclipse click File -> Import -> General > Existing Projects into Workspace ...

Comment: Thanks all, especially rik. Moving the project added a folder named like the project to my path. I couldn't change that. Now I have deleted and re-imported it like you suggested. All the settings seem to be still there, even the connection data (for aptana, wich I did not mention).

Answer (score 1):

You can at project level use refactor>move to move that code to a new location 
Not sure if that is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the location by right click on the project folder, then Refactor->Move...
Then Browse to new folder, note that new location can not be in the current workspace.